# Google Auth Page always shown, how to Auth only first time

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am making a calendar app with flutter using [googleApi](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) library.

but, When you turn off the app, need to auth again in web site.
i want auth only first time.

is it possible?

// mycode

```
get _SCOPES => [CalendarApi.CalendarScope];
  await clientViaUserConsent(_clientID, _SCOPES, prompt)
        .then((AuthClient client) async {
      CalendarClient.calendar = CalendarApi(client);
      calendarId = await CalendarClient.calendar.calendarList
          .list()
          .then((value) => value.items[0].id);
    });

void saveData(AccessCredentials credentials) {
    GetStorage().write(credetialKey, {
      "accessTokenData": credentials.accessToken.data,
      "accessTokenExpiry": credentials.accessToken.expiry.toString(),
      "refreshToken": credentials.refreshToken,
      "scopes": credentials.scopes,
      "idToken": credentials.idToken
    });
  }

  AccessCredentials getCredetial() {
    try {
      var map = GetStorage().read(credetialKey);
      return AccessCredentials(
          AccessToken("Bearer", map["accessTokenData"] as String,
              DateTime.parse(map["accessTokenExpiry"])),
          map["refreshToken"],
          map["scopes"].cast<String>(),
          idToken: map["idToken"] as String);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }


Client cli = Client();
    var c = await refreshCredentials(_clientID, getCredetial(), cli)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    authenticatedClient(cli, c);
```

error :
DetailedApiRequestError(status: 401, message: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access tok

Comment: You should try something like [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev) for state management. [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial) is an example project to look at.

Answer (score 1):

You can save user session using for example `sharedPreferences`. Each time the user launch the app your must first check if the session is saved so you can skip the auth process, otherwise you initiate the authentication

Comment: thx for user answer. but idk what to save, i add more code

Comment: Are you actually calling your `saveData(AccessCredentials credentials)` function ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it.

save AccessCredentials,
and use autoRefreshingClient;

```
   Client cli = Client();
    var c = await refreshCredentials(_clientID, getCredetial(), cli)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    cli = autoRefreshingClient(_clientID, c, cli);
```